# Laravel 5 Eloquent scope join and select specific columns

Tags: laravel, scope, eloquent

I have an Eloquent model and in the model I am using a scope query to do a join.  This all works fine but I am trying to figure out how in the scope query to select only certain columns from the joined table.

Here is the method in my controller.

```
$accounts = Account::creator()->get();
```

Here is the scope query in the model

```
public function scopeCreator($query) {
        $query->leftJoin('users','users.id','=','accounts.creator_id');
}
```

This works but it returns **all** the columns from accounts and users but I only want all the columns from accounts and only 2 columns from users.

I tried this...

```
public function scopeCreator($query) {
        $query->leftJoin('users','users.id','=','accounts.creator_id')->select(array('id','user_name'));
}
```

However this returns only those 2 fields from users and ignores the columns from accounts.  I know how to do this with 2 different models but that means I have to create a useless model.  This scope query functionality is great if I can just get this part figured out.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You may try this:

```
->select('accounts.*', 'users.id as uid','users.user_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

However this post is very old..

I did like to point out the following

if you would use selectRaw

```php
->selectRaw('`users`.`id` as uid');
```

In this case it will not replace the original select but add the columns additional. As this is not documented as far as i know. It is very useful if you want to chain multiple join scopes.

Also if you don't know the original select statement, and it can be dynamic.

Furthermore you can extend/override the default 'newQuery' method, to change the default behavior when using scopes

like this

```php
    public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true): Builder
    {
        return parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted)->select('table_name.*');
    }
```

However i would recommend to use the selectRaw over changing the default behavior of the newQuery(), as this might get you in trouble/conflicts in some cases.